# Calculating multiple input values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple items, where you are able to input the QTY. I have wrote the function but it only works for the first item.

I used the same classNames and ID's in the HTML, So I think it would add up everywhere there is a input.

I put it in a fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/detgz2Ls/

I have to keep everything with the same class/ID's, because this is going to be a list that is able to generate multiple items dynamically.

```
<body>
<div class="main">
<span class="title">A Title</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="item">
  <span>Item 1</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="cost">$100.00</span>
</div>
<div id="qty">
  <label>QTY:</label><input placeholder="0" class="qty-item">
  <p class="error"></p>
</div>
<div class="tot">
  <span><label>TOTAL</label> $0.0</span>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="main">
<span class="title">A Title</span>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="item">
   <span>Item 2</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="cost">$50.00</span>
</div>
<div class="qty">
  <label>QTY:</label><input placeholder="0" class="qty-item">
  <p class="error"></p>
</div>
<div class="tot">
  <span><label>TOTAL</label> $0.0</span>
</div>
  </div>

<div class="calc-button">
<button id="calc">Calculate Prices</button>
</div>
```

//JavaScript

```
const total = document.querySelector(".tot")
 price = document.querySelector(".cost").innerHTML;
 let textval = document.querySelector('.qty-item');
const cal = document.getElementById("calc");
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('.error');

cal.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){

let xPrice =price.split("$");
let parsePrice = parseFloat(xPrice[1]);
if(textval.value==="" || isNaN(textval.value)){

console.log("error");

}else {
let x = parseFloat(textval.value);
let y =parsePrice;

let z = x * y;

total.innerText = z.toFixed(2);
}
});
```

Comment: querySelector selects the first element only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use `querySelectorAll` to find all elements, not just the first one.

Then you have to iterate over whole collection of these elements (`for` loop).

```
const total = document.querySelectorAll(".tot")
const price = document.querySelectorAll(".cost"); // remove .innerHTML here -- elements collection has no .innerHTML, no .value, etc.
let textval = document.querySelectorAll('.qty-item');
const cal = document.getElementById("calc");
const errorMessage = document.querySelectorAll('.error');

cal.addEventListener('mouseover',function(e){
    // loop through all price elements
    for (var i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
        let xPrice =price[i].innerHTML.split("$"); // use .innerHTML here
        let parsePrice = parseFloat(xPrice[1]);

        if(textval[i].value==="" || isNaN(textval[i].value)){
            setMessage("Please enter a number",'red');          
        } else {
            let x = parseFloat(textval[i].value);
            let y =parsePrice;

            let z = x * y;

            total[i].innerText = z.toFixed(2);
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o92nz1gm/2/